# Removing KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, uninstall, plasma

So, I installed KDE Plasma so I could try it out, I thought it would just install the desktop environment, but it apparently it also installed the boot screen too. I managed to remove the DE and everything else I deemed useless, but I can't seem to remove the boot screen, how do I put back to the normal Ubuntu boot screen?

Comment: By boot screen I assume you mean the plymouth screen which is shown on boot, shutdown/reboot instead of messages; this is just a graphic and can be changed - and isn't considered part of the DE (but installing a -desktop file will cause it to be changed..)  Change it back, or change it to something one you like

Comment: Yes, I want my splash screen back that came with the install of Ubuntu.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!!!